# Enable startup application programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, startup, regedit

I 've an aplication which puts another application in startup.
I've put the latter exe in startup using the following
code:

```cs
string strExeFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string strWorkPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strExeFilePath);
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
{
    key.SetValue("my_service_name", strWorkPath + "\\MyProgram.exe");
}
```

It successfully put the entry in regedit. `'my_service_name'` is listed in the `'startup'` tab of the Task Manager also, But its in `'Disabled'`  state.

How can I enable it programmatically while adding to regedit? Why is it not `'Enabled'` by default?.

Comment: Check if the Path to the `MyProgram.exe` actually exist? Maybe there is no `exe` ommited during compilation for some reason. You could also try to but the path in `"`.

Comment: If you need a service application, why don't you write an NT Service instead?